# How much of a large collection of files is spatial data?

Tags: data-management, storage

We need to determine how much of the 6.5 TB used space on a shared network drive is geographic or spatial data. It's a squirrels nest, built up over 3 decades from hundreds of people (though by volume mostly in past 3 years) across all walks of business using a variety of naming and filing standards -- including none and the dreaded "misc".

[image: Oh oh. <7% free space]

*"Spatial"* in this context is anything produced by ArcView 3, ArcInfo, ArcGIS, PCI, ER Mapper, Global Mapper, QGIS, DNR Garmin, Basecamp, MapInfo ...

My plan of the moment is a simple brute force itemization of file extensions, at least to get us some ballpark estimates.

Singular types like shapefiles and ArcInfo grids & coverages are easy as the extensions `.shp, .shx, .adf, ...` aren't used by anything else.

Shared types like DBase `.dbf` and images `.tif, .jpg,` offer complication, though ones larger than 300 MB are very likely spatial.

Before I hack together a personal and idiosyncratic solution. Has anyone solved this already?

Comment: Ideally, all of the spatial data saved should be registered in some kind of metadata repository, but sadly even in large enterprises it's just a mapped drive ;) *sigh*. Faced this problem earlier, but instead of just estimating the size, I've gone through the piles and categorized the data, moved things around, and registered everything in a repository to keep track on what exists. Good luck with this tedious work, hope things will work out well for you.

Comment: gdalinfo and ogrinfo can auto detect format from a single file, and will list other detected files identified as belonging to a data source, so can be used to audit and organize

Comment: Its an intractable problem, not least because of a lack of agreement on what counts as spatial. A PNG image of my cat (if I had one) and a PNG format of aerial imagery both look the same, even to GDAL/OGR. That aerial imagery PNG might or might not be spatial depending on your opinion, or depending on the existence of a world file that may be in another directory, or on some users' desktop. Or the PNG is spatial if its in a specific directory structure that makes it Z/X/Y tiles..

Comment: Only partial support, but if on Windows, I've often started with a GUI solution to help figure out priority places to start. Check out [WinDirStat](https://windirstat.info/) - note there are linux and macosx variants.

Answer (score 1):

There's always some manual effort in this type of task, but I would use something like this as a starting point.  I found the basic code as `vahid abdi`'s response to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654099/get-the-sum-by-file-extensions-in-python) and just modified it a tiny bit to be compatible with both Python 2 and 3.  It's rough, and I would suggest improving the script in order to sort/filter the data for specific extensions or sort by total size as well as adding easy filtering for specific extensions.  I ran this and found that we have 2.6 GB of file databases (.gdf).

```
import os
import collections
extensions = collections.defaultdict(int)
size = collections.defaultdict(int)

for path, dirs, files in os.walk('./'):
   for filename in files:
       extensions[os.path.splitext(filename)[1].lower()] += 1
       size[os.path.splitext(filename)[1].lower()] += os.path.getsize(path+os.sep+filename)

for key,value in extensions.items():
    print ('Extension: ', key, ' ', value, ' items')

for key,value in size.items():
    print ('Extension: ', key, ' ', value, ' size')
```